# Given two numbers, a perfect square 's' and any positive integer 'd' is there a situation where s, s+d, s+2d, and s+3d are all perfect squares?

Tags: square-numbers

I have been messing around with a question over the last few months and haven't been able to make any headway.

Say you have a square number 's' and another positive integer (square or otherwise) 'd'. Is there a situation where s, s+d, s+2d, and s+3d are all square numbers?

Using a python script, I have found mounds of solutions up to the s+2d case, but haven't found any solutions that also satisfy s+3d. Am I in over my head here?

Example:

- s = 2500
- d = 60000
- s = $50^2$
- s + d = 2500 + 60000 = 62500 = $250^2$
- s + 2d = 2500 + 120000 = 122500 = $350^2$
- s + 3d = 2500 + 180000 = 182500 = 427.2001... (fail)

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  In order for MathJax commands to be effective, they must be enclosed in `$` signs.

Comment: Thanks, have fixed my exponents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no solutions with 4 squares in an arithmetic progression. The proof seems involved. See https://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath044/kmath044.htm

Comment: Thanks! I will take a look.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruum), you're in good company.  The non-existence of $4$ squares in arithmetic progression was conjectured by Fermat and proved by Euler.